# famo.us dependency injection

Tags: angularjs, famo.us

This is my config.js file

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',  'famous','ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils'];
```

This is the controller I use

```
angular.module('famoanimations').controller('FamoanimationsController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', '$famous','Authentication', 'Famoanimations',
    function($scope, $famous,$stateParams, $location, Authentication, Famoanimations)]
```

But i cant get the famo.us dependency injection in my Angular.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you sourced all the required files, your module must also explicitely depend on the `'famous.angular'` module.

Note : you also have an error in your controller function parameters, which don't match the dependencies. In current code, your `$famous` param will be initialized with the `$stateParams` dependency.